# Tikz: Alignment within fit box, text wrapping and top alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, fit

I'm new to tikz, and trying to generate a diagram with multiple fit boxes. These have anchor labels, but I can't seem to get the labels to wrap within the box for nodes `x1, a3, f3`.

I also want to align all these boxes at the top boundary, like nodex `x1, a3` are currently.

How should I accomplish this? Code and output below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, 
                 fit,        
                 positioning, 
               }

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
  allnodes/.style={draw=black, thick, rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm, text width=10em, align=center, 
    minimum height=1cm},
  boundbox/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=4mm,   text width=5em,draw},
  vhilit/.style={draw=red, thick, dotted,
    inner sep=1em},
  hhilit/.style={draw=black, thick, densely dotted,
    inner xsep=2em,
    inner ysep=.5em},
  line/.style={thick, -latex, shorten >= 2pt}
  ]

  \node (p1) [allnodes] {jabberwocky fives: How four data can be four to sixers the sixers?};   
  \node (p2) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of p1] {jabberwocky crocodile for a sixers system};
  \node (p3) [allnodes, below=0.75cm  of p2] {jabberwocky heavens crocodile four heavens rolleres symptoms in four};
  \node (p4) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of p3] {jabberwocky sixers in bus fives in crocodile}; 
  \node (p5) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of p4] {jabberwocky sixers in four sixers heavens};        
  \node[boundbox, fit=(p1) (p2) (p3) (p4) (p5), label={[anchor=north]north:fives 1: four heavens in heavens}] (x1) {};
  \node (e1) [allnodes, right=2cm of p1] {H1: crocodile four sixers four};  
  \node (e2) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of e1] {H2: crocodile four jabberwocky four Data heavens};
  \node (e3) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of e2] {H1 vs H2: whizzbangs};
  \node (e4) [allnodes, below=1.5cm of e3] {D1: crocodile four text fives rolleres};    
  \node (e5) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of e4] {D2: whizzbangs fives four only heavens rolleres symptoms}; 
  \node (e6) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of e5] {D1 vs D2: whizzbangs of differential crocodile};
  \node [boundbox, fit=(e1) (e2) (e3), label={[anchor=north]north:whizzbangs 1}] (a1) {};
  \node [boundbox, fit=(e4) (e5) (e6), label={[anchor=north]north:whizzbangs 2}] (a2) {};
  \node [boundbox,fit=(a1) (a2),label={[anchor=north]north:fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens rolleres}] (a3) {};
  \node (d1) [allnodes, right=2cm of e1] {A1: jabberwocky in RL, rolleres of crocodile};    
  \node (d2) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of d1] {H1 vs A1: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers};
  \node (d3) [allnodes, right=1cm of d1] {A2: jabberwocky in RL, four crocodile representation of new jabberwocky, rolleres of crocodile};
  \node (d4) [allnodes, below=0.75cm of d3] {H2 vs A2: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers}; 
  \node [boundbox, fit=(d1) (d2), label={[anchor=north]north:whizzbangs 3}] (f1) {};
  \node [boundbox, fit=(d3) (d4), label={[anchor=north]north:whizzbangs 4}] (f2) {};
  \node [boundbox, fit=(f1) (f2), label={[anchor=north]north:fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens problems}] (f3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I would suggest to use nodes instead of labels. Fitting doesn't take labels into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
               }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset join/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 6mm,
  start chain = going below,
box/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners,
              text width=10em, align=left, minimum height=1cm,
              font=\footnotesize,
              on chain},
FITout/.style = {box, thin,inner xsep=1mm, inner ysep=6mm, yshift=12mm, fit=#1},
FITinn/.style = {FITout=#1,inner ysep=3mm, yshift=-2mm},
every label/.style = {text width=11em, align=center, 
                      font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                ]
\node (p1) [box] {jabberwocky fives: How four data can be four to sixers the sixers?};
\node (p2) [box] {jabberwocky crocodile for a sixers system};
\node (p3) [box] {jabberwocky heavens crocodile four heavens rolleres symptoms in four};
\node (p4) [box] {jabberwocky sixers in bus fives in crocodile};
\node (p5) [box] {jabberwocky sixers in four sixers heavens};
\node[FITout={(p1) (p5)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]{fives 1: four heavens in heavens}}] (x1) {};
%%
\node (e1) [box, 
            right=of p1] {H1: crocodile four sixers four};
\node (e2) [box] {H2: crocodile four jabberwocky four Data heavens};
\node (e3) [box] {H1 vs H2: whizzbangs};
\node (e4) [box] {D1: crocodile four text fives rolleres};
\node (e5) [box] {D2: whizzbangs fives four only heavens rolleres symptoms};
\node (e6) [box] {D1 vs D2: whizzbangs of differential crocodile};
\node [FITinn={(e1)(e3)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 1}] (a1) {};
\node [FITinn={(e4) (e6)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 2}] (a2) {};
\node [FITout={(a1) (a2)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]{fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens rolleres}}] {};
%%
\node (d1) [box,
            right=of e1] {A1: jabberwocky in RL, rolleres of crocodile};
\node (d2) [box] {H1 vs A1: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers};
\node (d3) [box,
            right=4mm of d1] {A2: jabberwocky in RL, four crocodile representation of new jabberwocky, rolleres of crocodile};
\node (d4) [box] {H2 vs A2: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers};
\node [FITinn={(d1) (d2)}, 
       label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 3}] (f1) {};
\node [FITinn={(d3) (d4)}, 
       label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 4}] (f2) {};
\node [FITout={(f1) (f2)}, 
       label={[anchor=north, text width=21em]{fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens problems}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would reconsider the design of the last nodes column. In my opinion it would be better if the frames were in one column. Than you will able to use bigger font size and bigger distances between columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
               }

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below,
box/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners,
              text width=11em, align=center, minimum height=1cm,
              on chain},
FITout/.style = {box, thin,inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=7mm, yshift=14mm, fit=#1},
FITinn/.style = {FITout=#1,inner ysep=4mm, yshift=-2mm},
every label/.style = {text width=11em, align=center, 
                      font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
                ]
\node (p1) [box] {jabberwocky fives: How four data can be four to sixers the sixers?};
\node (p2) [box] {jabberwocky crocodile for a sixers system};
\node (p3) [box] {jabberwocky heavens crocodile four heavens rolleres symptoms in four};
\node (p4) [box] {jabberwocky sixers in bus fives in crocodile};
\node (p5) [box] {jabberwocky sixers in four sixers heavens};
\node[FITout={(p1) (p5)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]{fives 1: four heavens in heavens}}] (x1) {};
%%
\node (e1) [box, 
            right=of p1] {H1: crocodile four sixers four};
\node (e2) [box] {H2: crocodile four jabberwocky four Data heavens};
\node (e3) [box] {H1 vs H2: whizzbangs};
\node (e4) [box] {D1: crocodile four text fives rolleres};
\node (e5) [box] {D2: whizzbangs fives four only heavens rolleres symptoms};
\node (e6) [box] {D1 vs D2: whizzbangs of differential crocodile};
\node [FITinn={(e1)(e3)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 1}] (a1) {};
\node [FITinn={(e4) (e6)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 2}] (a2) {};
\node [FITout={(a1) (a2)}, 
      label={[anchor=north]{fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens rolleres}}] {};
%%
\node (d1) [box,
            right=of e1] {A1: jabberwocky in RL, rolleres of crocodile};
\node (d2) [box] {H1 vs A1: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers};
\node (d3) [box] {A2: jabberwocky in RL, four crocodile representation of new jabberwocky, rolleres of crocodile};
\node (d4) [box] {H2 vs A2: whizzbangs of crocodile four sixers and sixers};
\node [FITinn={(d1) (d2)}, 
       label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 3}] (f1) {};
\node [FITinn={(d3) (d4)}, 
       label={[anchor=north]whizzbangs 4}] (f2) {};
\node [FITout={(f1) (f2)}, 
       label={[anchor=north, text width=21em]{fives 2: four heavens rolleres crocodile for ill-heavens problems}}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I'll keep it as in the first solution you posted, since adding the needed links make it clearer that way.